# Using php variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, function, variables

I know I am doing this totally wrong and haven't got an idea how to do this.. basically I have a javascript function and trying to use php to declare as array all teams if round equals to 1. The teams and round will come from the parameters in function teamElement()

```
  function teamElement(round, team, isReady) {

  <?php if(round == 1)  $round2_array[] = team) ?>

  document.write('<p>round: ' + round + '<br>team ' + team.name + '<br> is ready ' + isReady);
```

...

Anyone can help with this please?

many thanks.

Comment: You cannot use Javascript variable 'team' inside PHP code.  <?php if(round == 1)  $round2_array[] = team) ?>

Comment: You are going to have to use AJAX for that.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your code, specifically this part:

```
function teamElement(round, team, isReady) {
  <?php if(round == 1)  $round2_array[] = team) ?>
```

I see you lack of some basic knowledge: Javascript is a client side scripting language, while PHP is a server side scripting language. PHP and Javascript are executed in two very different moments (generally PHP first and then Javascript (without using AJAX)). Therefore they cannot share variables *that easily*.

There are ways, though, to connect the two of them:

To pass a PHP variable to a Javascript script you could simply use string interpolation or the templating features of PHP:

```
var x = <?php echo $x; ?>;
```

Just notice that that is considered **very bad** practice and you should use AJAX here as well.

To pass a Javascript variable to a PHP script you can use AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML), to execute a PHP script "in the background", after the page is loaded. In this regard I suggest you to take a look at the nice [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library which provides a very helpful [set of functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for this task.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in this case is there anyway I use SQL statement to insert the teams from the team parameter in the teamElement function if that makes sense?

Comment: @KarimAli, assuming you are executing the query from PHP, yes you can: with AJAX.